# How can I get with org-store-link relative path instead of absolute?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

How can I get with org-store-link relative path instead of absolute?

I tried M-x customize-variable RET org-store-link, but did not work.
Or do I have to customize it anywhere else?

Answer (score 13):

The variable you need to customize is `org-link-file-path-type`. It doesn't appear in the org manual, but it's documentation is available via `C-h v`:

> Documentation:
>   How the path name in file links should be stored.
>   Valid values are:
>
> - **relative** Relative to the current directory, i.e. the directory of the file
>           into which the link is being inserted.
> - **absolute**  Absolute path, if possible with ~ for home directory.
> - **noabbrev**  Absolute path, no abbreviation of home directory.
> - **adaptive**  Use relative path for files in the current directory and sub-
>           directories of it.  For other files, use an absolute path.